# ExpressJS internationalized routing

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

I am having a hard time understandig how to achieve it but is there such a middleware which can take care of the language routes. For example the english URL is `domain.com/en`, french is `domain.com/fr`. This is easy to achieve but there are a lot of exceptions. Lets say you have a route `domain.com/fr/posts/books/3214` and the user goes to `domain.com/posts/books/3214`, the server should obviously redirect to the appropriate language. Now in an i18n app there is a fallback language: for example if we have 3 languages and the fallback language is 'en'. Some websites just use an ordinary url `domain.com/posts` for the default language, but for alternative languages they add the language code `domain.com/de/posts` or `domain.com/fr/posts`. A good example is [mongodb.com](https://www.mongodb.com). The
[NextJS internationalized routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing) is one of the best i18n router i've seen so far.

How do you make the same thing in ExpressJS?

Isn't there just a library that takes care of all this 'junk' by itself?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186644/multi-language-routes-in-express-js) with great answers. Please do check it out for more answers. However, I found this to be the best method:

```js
var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , http = require('http')
  , i18n = require("i18n");

  var app = express();

i18n.configure({
    // setup some locales - other locales default to en silently
    locales:['de', 'en'],
    // disable locale file updates
    updateFiles: false
});

app.configure(function(){
  ...
  app.use(i18n.init);
  ...
});
// register helpers for use in templates
app.locals({
  __i: i18n.__,
  __n: i18n.__n
});
```

after this set the following to get all request

```js
// invoked before each action
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    // set locale
    var rxLocal = /^\/(de|en)/i;
    if(rxLocal.test(req.url)){
        var arr = rxLocal.exec(req.url);
        var local=arr[1];
        i18n.setLocale(local);
    } else {
        i18n.setLocale('de');
    }
    // add extra logic
    next();
});

app.get(/\/(de|en)\/login/i, routes.login);
```